Cannot get substring substitution to work, SET doesn't appear to assign the value,
I'm trying to write a batch to rename all MP4 files which have " p1" as part of the name to " -1-" (for instance, "File Name p1.mp4" renamed to "File Name -1-.mp4").  However, I cannot get the variables to perform the commands as I'd expect.  Ultimately, I'll change the "1" to an index and loop through for all the possible parts, but for now I'm just trying to get the basic code to work.
I know it's probably because I'm using the %, %% and ! incorrectly, but no matter how I code them, the results are consistently inconsistent - don't execute as my research says they should.
@ECHO OFF
Setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
 
:: Get FROM and TO values
::
REM set /p "parm1=Enter Original content to be modified: "
REM set /p "parm2=Enter New value to replace Original with: "
   set parm1= p1
   set parm2= -1-

   echo From: '%parm1%' to: '%parm2%'
   echo. 

:: Rename the content of the CURRENT folder
::
   set wDir="X:\Educational"
   cd /d %wDir%

@ECHO ON
   for /R %%f in ("*.mp4") do (
      echo Original '%%~nxf'  
      echo Original '!~nxf'  
      echo Original '!~nxf!' 
       
      set "wrk1=!wrk:%parm1%=%parm2%!"
      echo Replace f substr Parm1 with Parm2 in wrk1: Single %% crashes batch 
      echo                                          : '%%~nxf:%parm1%=%parm2%%%'
      echo                                          : '!~nxf:%parm1%=%parm2%!'
       
      set "wrk=%%~nxf"
      echo Assign wrk to Filename.ext: '%wrk%'
      echo                           : '%%wrk%%'
      echo                           : '!wrk!'
       
      set "wrk1=!wrk:%parm1%=%parm2%!"
      echo Replace Parm1 with Parm2 in wrk1: '%wrk1%'
      echo                                 : '%%wrk1%%'
      echo                                 : '!wrk1!'
       
      set "wrk2=%wrk: p1= -1-%"
      echo Replace using literals in wrk2: '%wrk2%'
      echo                               : '%%wrk2%%'
      echo                               : '!wrk2!'
       
      echo.
      exit
   )       


I've done batch coding since (cough, cough) the 80s, but in the last 4 or 5 years I've attempted to use the more advanced capabilities.  It usually takes days of trial and error (as I cannot find an adequate debugger utility), and even then it will run 5 or 6 times, and then the 7th will crash with wild results.  I've traced this to how I'm accessing or resolving variables for "use" in the process.
In this case, I've tried using various combinations of %, %% and !, to no avail.  Variables assign in one command, but won't in another.  Syntax copied from research (var names corrected), which apparently work per the post, will not work in my code.  Arg :(
This is the output log from the code above.  I've added comments (tagged with ***) throughout
Any guidance would be greatly appreciated.
*** Batch file is supposed to traverse the directory structure, renaming all MP$ viles which
*** have a " p1" in the name with " -1-", as follows
***    Original:  Filename p1.mp4
***      Result:  Filename -1-.mp4
***
*** Eventually, the "1" will be a number pulled from an index, 1 to 25, but for now I'm just 
*** trying to get the basic structure to work :(
 
From: ' p1' to: ' -1-'
 

*** Why is this iterance even here? 
*** Obviously, %%f is empty -> and, therefore, definitely doesn't have MP$ suffix  
***
 
*** Also, why is "echo " appearing on an echo line?  
*** If that is the "resolved" command being executed, then where is the output?
*** Shouldn't there be a following line with the echoed content (without command syntax)?
 
X:\Educational>for /R %f in ("*.mp4") do (
echo Original '%~nxf'    
 echo Original '!~nxf'    
 echo Original '!~nxf!'   
 set "wrk1=!wrk: p1= -1-!"  
 echo Replace f substr Parm1 with Parm2 in wrk1: Single % crashes batch   
 echo                                          : '%~nxf: p1= -1-%'  
 echo                                          : '!~nxf: p1= -1-!'  
 set "wrk=%~nxf"  
 echo Assign wrk to Filename.ext: ''  
 echo                           : '%wrk%'  
 echo                           : '!wrk!'  
 set "wrk1=!wrk: p1= -1-!"  
 echo Replace Parm1 with Parm2 in wrk1: ''  
 echo                                 : '%wrk1%'  
 echo                                 : '!wrk1!'  
 set "wrk2= p1= -1-"  
 echo Replace using literals in wrk2: ''  
 echo                               : '%wrk2%'  
 echo                               : '!wrk2!'  
 echo. 
 exit
) 

X:\Educational>(
echo Original 'Abandoned p1.mp4'    
 echo Original '!~nxf'    
 echo Original '!~nxf!'   
 set "wrk1=!wrk: p1= -1-!"  
 echo Replace f substr Parm1 with Parm2 in wrk1: Single % crashes batch   
 echo                                          : 'Abandoned p1.mp4: p1= -1-%'  
 echo                                          : '!~nxf: p1= -1-!'  
                *** echo 2 - appears to resolve name, but does not do substitute  
                *** echo 3 - ! doesn't work (might be unnecessar)  
 
 set "wrk=Abandoned p1.mp4"  
 echo Assign wrk to Filename.ext: ''  
 echo                           : '%wrk%'  
 echo                           : '!wrk!'  
                *** SET appears to work - name fully resolved, wrk var specified
                *** echo 1 - Indicates SET did NOT actually assign value  
                *** echo 2 - %% resolved as text %  
                *** echo 3 - ! doesn't do anything (differently than %%)  
 
 set "wrk1=!wrk: p1= -1-!"  
 echo Replace Parm1 with Parm2 in wrk1: ''  
 echo                                 : '%wrk1%'  
 echo                                 : '!wrk1!'  
                *** SET appears to work - name fully resolved, wrk var specified
                *** echo 1 - Indicates SET did NOT actually assign value  
                *** echo 2 - %% resolved as text %  
                *** echo 3 - ! doesn't do anything (differently than %%)  
 
 set "wrk2= p1= -1-"  
 echo Replace using literals in wrk2: ''  
 echo                               : '%wrk2%'  
 echo                               : '!wrk2!'  
                *** SET appears to work, even though the Substitution fails
                *** echo 1 - Indicates SET did work
                ***          Why wasn't it assigned to " p1= -1-" 
                *** echo 2 - %% resolved as text %  
                *** echo 3 - ! doesn't do anything (differently than %%)  
 
 echo. 
 exit
) 
 
*** Why does this group of echo's even appear? 
*** if "exit" performed as indicated, there are no more commands after the last )
*** Plus, why does it re-echo the last FOR iterance?
***
Original 'Abandoned p1.mp4'  
Original '~nxf'  
Original '' 
Replace f substr Parm1 with Parm2 in wrk1: Single % crashes batch 
                                         : 'Abandoned p1.mp4: p1= -1-%'
                                         : ' p1= -1-'
Assign wrk to Filename.ext: ''
                          : '%wrk%'
                          : 'Abandoned p1.mp4'
Replace Parm1 with Parm2 in wrk1: ''
                                : '%wrk1%'
                                : 'Abandoned -1-.mp4'
Replace using literals in wrk2: ''
                              : '%wrk2%'
                              : ' p1= -1-'

 
*** Also, 90% of the time, when I run this batch file from Command terminal, the terminal closes
*** at the end of the Batch execute.  10% of the time, I can run the Batch from a single terminal
*** window multiple times and the terminal will not close until I exit manually.  I cannot  
***    why as the command entered is always the same;
***       renameparts.bat X:\Educational >parts.log 2>&1



Welcome to StackOverFlow. Please take the [tour]. Also please read [ask] a good question. Your should always provide a [mcve] of the code you are using that reproduces the problem.  Emphasis on minimal.

The placeholder %%f in for (%f outside .bat) is not a variable, and features that work on variables like %var:replace=with% don't apply to it. You must use (copy to) an actual variable, and you must use delayedexpansion for TWO reasons:
it's inside a for body AND it uses normal expansion within the reference.
setlocal delayedexpansion
for /r %%f in (*.mp4) do ( set "var=%%f" & echo rename "%%f" "!var:%parm1%=%parm2%!" )
rem if this shows what you want, remove the echo to run for real

If your filenames didn't include spaces you wouldn't need the quotes
in the rename; the ones on the set are still useful to prevent var T
from containing an extra space at the end, which is harmless as the
second argument to rename but in other cases can be a problem.
This is almost certainly a duplicate but I don't have time to search right now; maybe later.

   for /R %%f in ("*.mp4") do (
      REM the following line is redundant. 'wrk' is not yet defined
      REM on first entry, and the value is overwritten 2 lines later
      set "wrk1=!wrk:%parm1%=%parm2%!"
      
      set "wrk=%%~nxf"
       
      set "wrk1=!wrk:%parm1%=%parm2%!"
       
      set "wrk2=%wrk: p1= -1-%"
      
      REM display all variables that start `wrk`
      SET wrk
       
      echo.
      REM The `exit` command will terminate the batch or return to caller
      REM if the routine is `call`ed.
      REM exit
   )    

I haven't tried the above. It's purely theoretical.
I've removed the echo commands which, while they display useful(?) data, appear to obscure the flow.
Use set "var=value" for setting string values - this avoids problems caused by trailing spaces. Don't assign " or a terminal backslash or Space. Build pathnames from the elements - counterintuitively, it is likely to make the process easier. If the syntax set var="value" is used, then the quotes become part of the value assigned.
Note that your set code has a Space after the = This will include the space in the value assigned. If you place a space before the =, this will include the space in the variable to which the value is assigned.
I prefer to avoid ADFNPSTXZ (in either case) as metavariables (loop-control variables) 
ADFNPSTXZ are also metavariable-modifiers which can lead to difficult-to-find bugs 
(See `for/f` from the prompt for documentation)

So - rewrite
@ECHO OFF
Setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
 
:: Get FROM and TO values
::
:: Rename the content of the CURRENT folder
::
set wDir="X:\Educational"

:: Make wDir the current directory
PUSHD %wDir%

for /R %%e in ("*.mp4") do (
  for /L %%y in (1,1,99) do (
       
    set "wrk=%%~nxe"
       
    set "wrk1=!wrk: p%%y.= -%%y-.!"
   
    if "!wrk!" neq "!wrk1!" echo ren "%%e" "!wrk1!"      
  ) 
)

POPD

Tested with normal alphanumerics and space. *NOT tested with "Poison characters" (those with special meaning to the batch language, such as !%~&^()
First, switch current directory to the directory nominated. The POPD command after the nested for loops restores the original current directory.
for each '.mp4' filename in the directory tree...
For %%y in 1 to 99, step 1 (for /? from the prompt or many SO articles for docco)...
Set wrk and calculate the new filename wrk1 by replacing  p%%y. with  -%%y-.
wrk and wrk1 may be different (but won't be if the filename being examined is whatever.mp4 for instance) and if so, attempt the rename.
The required REN commands are merely ECHOed for testing purposes. After you've verified that the commands are correct, change ECHO REN to REN to actually perform the rename.
Naturally, 99 is simply the maximump? expected.

Thank you!  I knew it would be something simple, but nothing I found (wasn't looking for it, so didn't realize why examples did this) stipulated that the %%f couldn't be used as a "normal" variable.  That does explain quite a bit.
As for the space in the Set, I needed (intended) that to be there.  The search/replace needs to have a preceding space or the value could be part of the "real" filename.
I'll try it tomorrow.

Don't "copy exactly". Cut-and-paste to avoid transcription errors and save time. Batch syntax takes a little getting used to. Seemingly minor changes can be disastrous, so copy-and-paste to a text-editor is probably the best approach. Don't use a word-processor as they have a habit of reformatting the text in an attempt to make it seem more like English. I use Editplus but there are others that a good Googling will find like Notepad++. Notepad is barely adequate as it tries to word-process code.

Oops - just saw your post.  Can't figure out why ECHO ON, isn't showing the command as typed (or partially parsed) as well as the executed command and the command output.
I use SPF editor - it's a PC version of a main frame line editor.  I used it "back in the old days" when working on ... main frames.  Best line editor ever, IMO.
Thank you for the help.
